# Why are explicitly positioned nodes affected by 'on chain' as a default?

Tags: tikz-styles

I want to place an X on a connection to show it is impossible. This is the MWE; the full example has a large number of chained nodes, hence the default, even though the MWE has no chained nodes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
  start chain=going below,
  every node/.style={%
    on chain,
    },
]
\node (a) {a};
\node [below=4cm of a] (b) {b};
\node [below left=2.8cm of a] (c) {c};
\draw (c) -- (a) node [pos=0.5] {X};
\draw (c) -- (b) node [pos=0.5] {X};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which gives me the left-hand result, while omitting `on chain` gives me what I need, on the right:

[image: Bad] ... [image: Good]

I would have thought that `pos=0.5` shouldn't be affected by the chain offset, but it appears to be, since `going right` gives this:

[image: Bad in another direction]

My questions, then, are:

1. Is this a bug in TikZ, or in my understanding?
2. I know there is no `off chain` key, but is there a key that means the opposite of `on chain`?
3. Is there another way of doing what I need? (preferably without massive re-editing of my source)

Comment: Do you need every/node/.style ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick fix: limit `on chain` within a `scope`. (use `continue chain` to, you know, continue the same chain in another `scope`.)

A quick explanation: `on cahin` places every *free* node in the current chain, including marks, which are essentially nodes.

A longer explanation: For users' convenience, Ti*k*Z does not draw a node immediately after it sees a `node`. Think about how many keys are responsible to the position: `pos`, `shift`'s, `every nodes`, etc. It is not surprised that those keys just cause appropriate transformations. After processing those keys, Ti*k*Z tries to draw a node at the (current) origin (implicitly) but `on chain` then inserts yet another shift. This ruins everything and follows your question.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=9,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=2 going below]
    \begin{scope}[nodes={on chain=2}]
        \node(a){a};
        \node[below=4cm of a](b){b};
        \node[below left=2.8cm of a](c){c};
        \draw(c)--(a)node[pos=0.3]{X}node[pos=0.5]{X}node[pos=0.7]{X};
    \end{scope}
    \draw(c)--(b)node[pos=0.3]{X}node[pos=0.5]{X}node[pos=0.7]{X};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The chain option does not constrain the position of the node. It only alters the key `<chain direction>= of (\tikzchainprevios)`  (with `positioning` syntax). In other words you can still place it freely but when it is placed relative to that last given coordinate it will change the anchor and the relative spacing. It will not force the node to be placed always under the previous. Otherwise you wouldn't be able to place `b` or `c` in the first place.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,calc,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
  start chain= C going below,
  every node/.style={on chain}
]
\node (a) {a};% This is chain-1
\node [below=4cm of a] (b) {b};% This is chain-2
\node [below left=2.8cm of a] (c) {c};% This chain-3
\tikzset{node distance=0mm}
\draw (c) -- (a) node [pos=0.5] {\tikzchainprevious};% Still below= of hence north anchored
\tikzset{node distance=-1cm}
\draw (c) -- (b) node [pos=0.5] {\tikzchainprevious};% Still below= of
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Chains are more suitable for easy input of consecutive nodes (possibly also `join`ed) along some directions that rarely changes. For freely placed nodes I would use `\chainin` lists instead.